# ESLint couldn't find the config "prettier" to extend from

Tags: eslint, prettier, prettier-eslint

I am trying to format my code using `eslint` but when I run `npm run lint -f` I get this output:

```js
    Oops! Something went wrong! :(
    ESLint: 6.8.0.
    ESLint couldn't find the config "prettier" to extend from. Please check that the name of the config is correct.   
    The config "prettier" was referenced from the config file in "/project/node_modules/eslint-plugin-prettier/eslint-plugin-prettier.js".
```

This is my dependences `package.json`

```json
    {
      "scripts": {
        "lint": "eslint \"**/*.{js,ts}\" --quiet --fix",
      },
      "private": true,
      "dependencies": {
        "tslib": "^1.11.1",
        "zone.js": "^0.10.3"
      },
      "devDependencies": {
        "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^2.30.0",
        "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^2.30.0",
        "codelyzer": "^5.2.2",
        "eslint": "^6.8.0",
        "eslint-config-google": "^0.14.0",
        "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.20.2",
        "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.1.3",
        "prettier": "2.0.5",
        
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 379, accepted):

I think you need to install `eslint-config-prettier` [see here](https://prettier.io/docs/en/integrating-with-linters.html)

Comment: And it should be added as a dev dependency i.e. `npm install --save-dev eslint-config-prettier`

Comment: Also, make sure you have an `.eslintrc` file in your project directory. [Configuration File Formats](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring/configuration-files#configuration-file-formats)

Comment: @OlyDungey Even after installing, the terminal outputs: "Failed to load plugin 'prettier' declared in '.eslintrc.js': Cannot find module 'eslint-plugin-prettier'"; and yes I also got a .eslintrc file. Had the whole Vue project setup and working, but all of a sudden it does no longer work.. very frustrating. Any idea how to fix?

Answer (score 0):

This did it for me,

```
npm install -D prettier eslint-config-prettier eslint-plugin-prettier
```

Comment: Please explain how this differs from the existing answer